# Enable one button when all my Ng-from is Valid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-form

```
 <div ng-show="!login.SecQuestions && !login.ResetUser">
                <h3>Answer security questions</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label>Please answer the following question(s)</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        *= required field
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul ng-repeat="Question in login.SecurityQuestions">
                    <li>
                        {{Question.Question}}
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <ng-form name="SecQuestionForm" novalidate>
                            <textarea name="SecurityAnswer" ng-model="Question.Answer" type="text" required></textarea>
                            <span style="color:red" ng-if="SecQuestionForm.SecurityAnswer.$dirty" ng-show="SecQuestionForm.SecurityAnswer.$invalid">required.</span>
                        </ng-form>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <button class="primaryButton" ng-disabled="ResetNamePass.SecQuestionForm.$invalid" ng-click="Continue_2()">Continue</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

**Dyanamic validation of ng-Form**
The button is enabled is not validating all the three required fields, its is enabled depending on the required-ness of the last Textarea.

Screen-shot of the error

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bz2v151kdXv8fjNsc0VGLVpOOFNoRklCcTdZNjFkOWprOEYteENJTUN1YUZUbHRVc3hNaFE&usp=sharing

Comment: AFAICS: You are applying the formname within a repeat, yielding the same formname (angular form) on each entry. Have you tried setting the form outside the repeat?

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine if you have something like this form

```
<form name='form'>
   <input name='name'></input>
   <button ng-disabled='!form.name'></button>
</form>
```

Hope it helps
Demo [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r9b34tsx/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Put Your ng-form inside one form and then add the condition on button for the validity of outer form.

```
<form novalidate name='form1'>
    <ul ng-repeat="Question in login.SecurityQuestions">
                        <li>
                            {{Question.Question}}
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <ng-form name="SecQuestionForm" novalidate>
                                <textarea name="SecurityAnswer" ng-model="Question.Answer" type="text" required></textarea>
                                <span style="color:red" ng-if="SecQuestionForm.SecurityAnswer.$dirty" ng-show="SecQuestionForm.SecurityAnswer.$invalid">required.</span>
                            </ng-form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <button class="primaryButton" ng-disabled="!form1.$valid" ng-click="Continue_2()">Continue</button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
</form>
```

outer form will be valid only if all the nested ng-forms are valid

Comment: I tried Wrapping my <ng-form name="SecQuestionForm" novalidate> inside another NG form, and it worked.

Comment: I think wrapping <ng-form name="SecQuestionForm" novalidate> inside simple <form > will also work.. so no need to put it in ng-form.

Comment: Yeaa,i could do that but my SPA has several other div's so validating a form would fire required-ness for all d div's.Hence ng-form was soln to go.

Answer (score 0):

[angular - Developer Guide - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

```
  <form name="form" class="css-form" novalidate>
  <div>
    Overwritten Email:
    <input type="email" ng-model="myEmail" overwrite-email name="overwrittenEmail" />
    <span ng-show="form.overwrittenEmail.$error.email">This email format is invalid!</span><br>
    Model: {{myEmail}}
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 `<form name="frmsignIn" ng-submit="login()" novalidate >
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" ></span>
  <div>
  <label for="email" >Email</label>
   <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="userName" ng-required="true"/>
   <span ng-show="frmsignIn.email.$dirty && frmsignIn.email.$error.required">*</span><span ng-show="frmsignIn.email.$dirty && frmsignIn.email.$error.email">Invalid email address</span>
    </div>
   <div>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
   <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" ng-required="true"/>
  <span ng-show="frmsignIn.password.$dirty && frmsignIn.password.$error.required">*</span>
   </div>
   <div>

    <button  type="submit" ng-disabled="frmsignIn.$invalid"  >  {{buttonText}}</button>

   </div>
   <div>
    <span ng-show="showErrorMsg">Invalid Email Address/Password.Please try again.</span>
   </div>
    </form>`
```